# Add space per 4 characters with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, string-formatting

What is the RegEx to put whitespace per 4 characters

For example I have an IBAN number like this

> **BE45898287271283**

I want to format it like this

> **BE45 8982 8727 1283**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You really need a regex? i'M sure i could get this to work with string compare functions

Comment: Make a reg ex which matches 4 characters and replace based on that with 4 characters and a space

Comment: @D.Rattansingh I never used string compare functions before

Comment: Strange how this question has other answers than the questions listed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this

```
string test = "BE45898287271283";
test = Regex.Replace(test, ".{4}", "$0 ").Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a RegEx;

```
foo = Regex.Replace(foo, ".{4}", "$0 ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex instead:

```
[a-z\d]{4}

string in="BE45898287271283";
string out = Regex.Replace("(?i)([a-z\\d]{4})", "$1 ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private string Group4(string s)
{
    string output="";
    for(int i=0; i < s.Length; i+=4)
        output+=s.Substring(i, 4) + ' ';

    return s.TrimEnd();
}
```